# How to convert string "yyyy mmm ABC" to "yyyymm" date format using Excel formula?

Tags: excel, string, date, excel-formula, string-operations

Suppose, in Excel, I have cell value equal to

```
"2020 Aug ABC"
```

I want to convert this to `202008` date format using an excel formula because I would want to use the output value, that is, 202008 to perform some operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is in `A1`:

```
=LEFT(A1,4) & TEXT((DATEVALUE(MID(A1,6,3) & " 1")),"mm")
```

Comment: Too similar for an answer... `=LEFT(A1,4)&TEXT(MONTH(1&MID(A1,6,3)),"00")`

Comment: thanks for your answer, may I know what is mm at the end refer to?

Comment: Actually it is Date format, which only shows month in two symbols (`08` instead of `8`)

Answer (score 1):

- Import "2020 Aug ABC" in cell A1
- Select A1 - Go to Data tab - Data Tools Area - Press Text to Columns
- Select Delimited - Press Next - Select Space - Press Next
- Press Finish
- In D1 import `=A1&RIGHT("0" & MONTH(DATEVALUE(B1&"1")),2)`

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or just using :

```
=TEXT(MID(A1,6,3)&LEFT(A1,4),"yyymm")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A1 = 2020 Aug ABC

B1

```
=LOOKUP(9^9,LEFT(A1,4)/1%+FIND(TEXT(ROW($1:$12)*28,"mmm"),A1)^0*ROW($1:$8))
```

Comment: What is the `9^9` bit doing?

Comment: A big number, shortening.

Answer (score 0):

Just another approach if your data is always same pattern.

```
=TEXT(DATEVALUE("01-"&MID(A1,6,3)&"-"&LEFT(A1,4)),"yyyymm")
```